# Mostrar respuestas de formulario en html con Jinja2 usando una api creada con fastAPI y subida en Heroku

Tags: python, api, heroku

estoy tratando de hacer una api con fastAPI (subida a heroku) y tengo un problema, la api recibe un formulario y procesa las respuestas con ciertos algoritmos, me gustaría que los resultados se mostraran en un html por eso uso Jinja2 pero al enviar un formulario me da un error y no encuentro la solución. Este es el código que tengo en la api:

```
   from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
   import json
   from pydantic import BaseModel
   from funciones import *
   from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
   from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
   from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

   app = FastAPI()

   templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

   @app.post("/analisis/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
   async def analisis(request = Request, nombre: str = Form(...), 
            edad: int = Form(...), 
            peso: int = Form(...),
            sexo: str = Form(...),
            cuestion1: int = Form(...),
            cuestion2: int = Form(...),
            cuestion3: int = Form(...),
            cuestion4: int = Form(...),
            cuestion5: int = Form(...),
            cuestion7: int = Form(...),
            cuestion8: int = Form(...),
            cuestion9: int = Form(...),
            cuestion10: int = Form(...),
            cuestion11: int = Form(...),
            cuestion12: int = Form(...),
            cuestion13: int = Form(...),
            cuestion14: list = Form(...),
            cuestion15: int = Form(...),
            cuestion16: int = Form(...)):


return templates.TemplateResponse("analisis.html", {"request" : request, 
                                                    "nombre" : nombre, 
                                                    "edad" : edad,
                                                    "peso" : peso,
                                                    "sexo" : sexo,
                                                    "cuestion 1" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 2" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 3" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 4" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 5" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 6" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 7" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 8" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 9" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 10" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 11" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 12" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 13" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 14" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 15" : cuestion1,
                                                    "cuestion 16" : cuestion1,})
```

Este es mi html que se encuentra en templates:

```
    <h1>Respuesta: {{ cuestion1 }} </h1>
```

y este es el error que veo en heroku logs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Vale el error está en que al definir la función puse -> request = Request y en la forma correcta es -> request : Request. 5 horas haciendo pruebas y viendo los errores para que el fallo sea este. En fin, la vida del programador.